# TypeError when run file with JS Module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, prettier

So I've started learning stuff about modules, but I've faced an error right away (probably it's not even about modules) and I've never seen in before.
I use VSCode Live Server for this as well.
My project tree is structured like this:
/modules

 - index.html

 - scripts.js

 - utils.html

The issue is - when I run a function from scripts.js console throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "prettier". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I don't even have Prettier extension installed. So where does an error comes from?

Here is my `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Modules</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./base.css">
</head>

<body>

  <script src="./scripts.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`scripts.js`

```js
import { format } from "prettier";
import { returnHi } from './utils.js';

const name = 'wes';

console.log(returnHi(name));

console.log('working');
```

And `utils.js`

```js
export function returnHi(name) {
    return `hi ${name}`;
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I've noticed that for some reason I'm trying to import prettier in scripts.js. No idea where it came from XD